# Jensen's inequality in derivation of EM algorithm

Tags: statistics, algorithms, statistical-inference

I am going through the derivation of EM algorithm and got stuck on understanding the following steps:
[Notes showing EM algortithm derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eyvW.png)

For the equality to hold, f(x) has to be an affine function. Why does setting $q(x)=p(x|z,\theta)$ make f(x) an affine function?

Comment: did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness ? I like how it is explained

Answer (score 1):

It said $f(x) = log \frac{p(x,z|\theta}{q(x)}$ be affine, it means the linear function with the translation. If $q(x) = p(x|z, \theta) = p(x, z|\theta)p(z|\theta)$, then $f(x)  = log(\frac{1}{p(z|\theta)})$ is a constant indepent of x, so it is affine function.
The choice of q(x) this way af is just one choice to get Jensen's inequality to achive equality.

Comment: So the constant function is also a type of affine function?

Comment: yes. affine func tion is a linear function plus constant.