# The proof of lemma 1 in Dempster's 1977 EM algorithm paper

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I am learning the proofs about general properties for the EM algorithm in Dempster's 1977 EM algorithm paper [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3dmY.png). In it I found that the proof of Lemma 1, which is attached below, is referred to a conclusion in Rao's statistical inference book [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzCVq.png).

---

[image]

---

But when I checked the (1e5.6) formulae, I found it is just the Jensen's equation. While (1e6.6), which is attached below, has an extra application condition that $\int_S(f-g)\geq0$, I suppose there shall be a corresponding  relationship between $\phi$ and $\phi'$. In contrast, Dempster's lemma 1 says that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ could be any pairs, which makes me confused. Could you please tell me which part of my thinking is wrong or an entire proof for this lemma?

---

[image]

---

I also found a related question on this topic: [Jensen's inequality in derivation of EM algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1652813/jensens-inequality-in-derivation-of-em-algorithm).
However, it is not totally the same.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3dmY.png) Dempster, Arthur P., Nan M. Laird, and Donald B. Rubin. "Maximum likelihood from incomplete data via the EM algorithm." Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological) 39, no. 1 (1977): 1-22.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzCVq.png) Rao, C.R., 1973. Linear statistical inference and its applications. New York: Wiley.

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking about this too. What I think is that the inequality can be showed using, that the KL-divergence is always greater than zero. I am using the definitions from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) here. Basically $z$ is the hidden variable and $x$ is the observed variable.

$$
H(\phi | \phi^{(t)}) \geq H(\phi^{(t)} | \phi^{(t)}) 
$$
By inserting the definitions and multiplying by $-1$, we get
$$
\sum_z p(z|x,\phi^{(t)}) \log p(z|x,\phi) \leq \sum_z p(z|x,\phi^{(t)}) \log p(z|X,\phi^{(t)})
$$
By bringing the sum on the left side we get
$$
\sum_z p(z|x,\phi^{(t)}) \log \frac {p(z|x,\phi)} {p(z|x,\phi^{(t)})} ) \leq 0
$$
This is basically the KL-divergence 
$$
\sum_z p(z|x,\phi^{(t)}) \log \frac {p(z|x,\phi^{(t)})} {p(z|X,\phi)} ) \geq 0
$$

This is also what is said in the definition of Jensen's inequality you mentioned.

Please note, that I am pretty new to this topic and unsure about the above solution.